# How do I prevent GRUB2 from automatically booting into an OS?

Tags: linux, fedora, multi-boot, grub2

I am dual-booting Fedora 16 and Windows 7, and using grub to handle booting. The default is set to Fedora, and I have a real problem with getting distracted during boot and having it boot into Fedora when I want to go to windows. I would like it to, instead of timing out and booting to the default, to just sit in GRUB until I choose one. How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2) wiki, if you set/add the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` directive and change the value to `-1`, you will cause GRUB2 to pause until you make a decision, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the grub time value to -1 will cause it to be disabled.
Alternatively, you can hit any key (like a cursor key) to disable the current boot menu countdown.
Editing the grub2 config file is [documented here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Timed_Display)
Remember that manual updates to the cfg file are overwritten by update-grub.

Answer (score 1):

Think you can either remove the 'timeout' entry or set it to -1

Comment: Where do I set that?